# Зависает консоль на Windows 10 с npm

Tags: консоль

Любая консоль, которую я использую не дает мне использовать команды. При попытке сделать npm install или npx, команда зависает и никак не планирует отвисать. При этом сама консоль работает отлично и команду в любой момент можно прервать. Не могу никак нагуглить эту проблему.

Node.js установлен, npm работает исправно. Версия npm 6.9.0

UPD: Решение продвинулось. Проблема с npm. Нужно выставить `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"`, вместо такого же адреса, но с https. Теперь npm зависает на стадии extract.

Comment: NodeJS установлен? Если нет то нужно будет его установить.

Comment: Если бы node.js не был установлен, то npm бы не запускался. Естественно он установлен. Проблема в том, что команды не выполняются. Они зависают и все.

Comment: Зависает любая команда или только те, для которых требуется интернет? Может быть фаервол блокирует соединение, и команды ждут завершения соединения по таймауту?

Comment: У вас явно что-то не так с доступностью npm-овского репозитория.